# Cycle detection in a pseudo-Latin square

Tags: permutations, latin-square

Given a matrix of size $m \times n$ with no repetition of values in rows or columns, is there an efficient method of detecting cycles?

For example, here is a sample matrix:

> 3  5  2  9  7  4
>    4  3  6  1  8  7
>    1  4  7  5  2  9
>    9  8  3  2  6  1
>    2  6  8  7  3  5

It has at least one permutation cycle of size 3:

> 3  5  2  9  7  4
>      4  **8**  **3**  1  **6**  7
>      1  4  7  5  2  9
>      9  **6**  **8**  2  **3**  1
>      2  **3**  **6**  7  **8**  5

The values 3, 6, and 8 in rows 2, 4 and 5 form a cycle.

The problem relates to [Kakuro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakuro) puzzles.  Nothing to do with solving them, but trying to detect whether any layout of a particular grid (of overlapping matrices)  makes it unsuitable. A cycle of any length within any sub-block would make that particular layout undesirable - since the sum of rows and columns is the same in each case, so the puzzle is *ambiguous*.

The matrices are not strictly *Latin* -  the number of symbols exceeds the rank. With just 9 symbols, the problem can be practically solved by exhaustive search. But what if my symbol set (allowed values) was larger, and the matrix correspondingly bigger?

My exhaustive search algorithm is:

For a given cycle length $p$ and 
candidate tl-corner position ($r$, $c$), I take all combinations of 
rows and columns that could form a $p \times p$ sub-matrix with that corner.

There are $k = C(n-r, p-1)$ possibilities for both row and column, for a total of $k^2$
candidate-sets.

 For each set I count the number of different values, $d$ in that set. If $d = p$ then it must be a cycle.